# How to secure WordPress REST API and self-built API if user logs in with on-premise ADFS single sign on

Tags: wordpress, rest, api, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on

I'm building a portal application with Reactjs for an institution and users need to be able to single sign on through our on-premise ADFS. I'm working solo on this project and this is my first big one as well, so I have some questions and also looking for validation of the solutions that I'm thinking about using.

There are two types of content that needs to go on this app. One is very general information that pertains to all users. The other is very specific information for the particular user logging in.

I decided to go with WordPress for the general information, since it's very easy to create pages on there and use their REST API to get all the pages I need for the portal app. The problem here is how do I securely hit that API without explicitly using a username and password somewhere in that process (JWT Authentication)? The user does not have any credentials with WordPress, only with our ADFS (3.0).

For the specific user-related information, I'd use my own self-built API and I think I can use OAuth 2 to secure it. The app will ask the ADFS server for a code, at which point, the user will be asked to log in through the ADFS login page. After successful login, the ADFS server will send the app the code, using which I can ask for and receive a JWT token from the ADFS server. Now I can use my API by sending this JWT token along with any requests. My API will then use the token signing certificate to validate it and thus secure the API. Would this work?

Thanks in advance for any help!